# Why I call fork() in C but make sys_clone() syscall instead? Why not sys_fork() syscall?

Tags: c, linux, fork, clone, system-calls

Here is my source code
test.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    pid_t pid;

    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){
        printf("new process\n");
    }else{
        printf("old process\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I compiled it by:

```
gcc test.c -o fork
```

And I found it make sys_clone() syscall instead of sys_fork() by strace.

```
$strace -o my ./fork
new process
old process
```

```
$cat my | grep clone
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f459f17d810) = 4415
```

```
$cat my | grep fork
execve("./fork", ["./fork"], 0x7ffc76ccbf00 /* 52 vars */) = 0
```

see clone() in the scripts? why not fork?

Comment: As a general rule, there is no requirement for libc implementation to abide to a certain mapping between user function and sys call - after all, it's purpose in life is to abstract away syscalls. The only requirement is to follow the specification. As long as `fork` does what is described, it is free to call any syscall or none at all.

Answer (score 1):

[`clone(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) is a Linux specific system call that superseded [`fork(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) system call.
So `clone` is used for creating all the "process-like" entities (for creating threads, implementing vfork, posix_spawn and so on) on Linux.
Basically, `fork` is equivalent to `clone` with specific flags. So that's why you see `clone` under `strace`.

Of course, the [POSIX `fork`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) isn't deprecated and isn't going to disappear. So use of `fork` isn't an issue. Just that C library implementations on Linux use `clone` system call to implement `fork`.

Answer (score 0):

In *some* versions of *several* C libraries for Linux (e.g. [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/)), the `fork` function is actually implemented by a call to `clone`

**Since these libraries are open source, you could download their source code and study it** (or even improve that source code)

See also [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [clone(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), [uname(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html), [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html), [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) etc.... and read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Perhaps some C libraries are using `clone` or `fork` depending of the result of some initial call to [uname(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html)

Read also some [good textbook on operating systems](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).